# Presenting a view controller based on a policy in swift

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I have some policy in my application which values are changed. For instance:

```
var canGoToPageX
```

when the value of `canGoToPageX` is true, user can be redirected to **"x"** view controller

```
if canGoToPageX {
   present X
}
```

this View controller is presented in several pages, if a developer forgets to write the if condition, user will be redirected to a page which he doesn't allowed.

I wanna do something to avoid this mistake
Is there any design pattern for this?

Comment: `canGoToPageX` is global or attached to every controller and how you will be changing it's value for every controller?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Thanks, canGoToPageX  is a global variable that is just for x view controller. I wanna avoid developer to present this view controller without checking this policy

Answer (score 0):

As if `canGoToPageX` is the global variable and based on that you need to restrict a `UIViewController` from access it and you are just worried about one case which is **developer can forget to put a condition**, then here is what you can do:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    checkIsControllerAccessible()
}

fileprivate func checkIsControllerAccessible() {
    if !canGoToPageX { //Restrictions
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You are not allowed to access this View", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (_) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
    }
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The `viewWillAppear` will always check whether it is accessible or not. This case will be useful when you are go back from one `UIViewController` and the `UIViewController` which you restrict to access to the user.

Let me know this helps or not?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that could solve this issue is to create a subclass of `UIViewController` that overrides the necessary presentation functions that `UIViewController` has and check whether the view controller that is about to be presented is of type "x" and whether the global `canGoToPageX` is true/false.

This approach would require the developer to subclass this new view controller class on view controllers that can potentially present "x", so it is still vulnerable to the developer forgetting something, but it encapsulates the conditional.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate the above approach:

```swift
import UIKit

// Global state holder
class SingletonStateHolder {
    static let shared = SingletonStateHolder()

    var canGoToX = false
}

// View controller that can only be presented if `canGoToX` is true
class XViewController: UIViewController {

}

// View controller subclass that view controllers who can potentially present x can subclass from
class SecureViewController: UIViewController {

    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if viewControllerToPresent is XViewController && !SingletonStateHolder.shared.canGoToX {
            return
        }

        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }

    override func show(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?) {
        if vc is XViewController && !SingletonStateHolder.shared.canGoToX {
            return
        }

        super.show(vc, sender: sender)
    }
}
```